# Getting started with Solr based search engine

Tags: php, mysql, search, solr

I want to implement a true search engine into a PHP/MySQL project. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what would be the optimal way to do something like this?

- search for users
- users are ranked/sorted on a variety of parameters

Such parameters could be: 
- number of comments made
- number of likes on your profile 
- geo distance from the end user

My real concern here is, search engines like Solr requires me to upload "documents"/data set. But since my data is "alive", should I constantly update the Solr documents every time user interacts on my website? In that case, it feels like a redundant database.

How does similar projects do?

Comment: Search engine indexes are frequently a "redundant database". You can always try using the full text search features in MySQL (depending on what version you're running) but Solr, ElasticSearch, Lucene etc are likely to have more features.

Comment: Yes, every time a relevant row is updated, you have to update the search index to maintain full searchability. If this is too expensive, you can always choose to have your index lag behind your model - in many cases it does not matter if a brand new update is not fully searchable for five minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. So I am on the right track :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general your concern is right: being an inverted-index based engine, Solr relies on that "immutable" structure for offering its features.

On top of that, depending on your context, there a lot of things that mitigates this aspect. I suggest you to check the SolrCloud capabilities, especially the Near Real Time search. Also dynamic sharding could be another thing, but that really depends on your scenario.

Comment: Using AWS already, I chose to try out Amazon CloudSearch which is Solr based.